# Common ways to tell the time

Tags: word-usage, formality, time

I'm a non-native speaker. In school, I was taught that the proper way of telling times in English is X `o' clock`.

In NAE, would it be common to omit *o' clock* and just say something like:

> It's eleven

in an informal context? Are there other commonly used ways to tell the time?

Comment: Yes, just the raw number is perfectly fine.  If it's not something-o'clock, you can also leave the hour implied, as in "It's about 10 after" (that is, 11:10) or "It's quarter to" (quarter to 11 = 10:45) if you trust that your listener is not so completely unaware of the time that they don't even know what hour it is.

Comment: To add to what Hellion said, "a quarter *till*" is also used in the US. In the UK it is almost always "a quarter *of*." BTW @Hellion you should make your comment an answer.

Comment: @Tom: I'm not sure I've *ever* heard *a quarter **of** [six, seven o'clock, etc]* from a BrE speaker. But it's certainly used by *American* authors in Google Books - the first two examples I found being these from [Tracie Peterson](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22already+a+quarter+of+seven%22) and [Mercedes Lackey.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22already+a+quarter+of+six%22) BrE is almost always *a quarter **to** six*.

Comment: FumbleFingers you could be right. It's not used often in my region (Midwest US) but I've definitely heard it used. It may be a different AmE dialect. Can't say why i associated it with BrE. The way I say it is "a quarter *tə* two" so the schwa can be taken as *to* or *till,* but if i leave off the number it's definitely "a quarter *till.*"

Comment: This is very much a matter of your local culture.  My grandmother and aunt (her daughter) used an unintelligible (to an 8-year-old) mixture of "half past", "ten of", "a quarter of", etc.  (All with no hour specified, and "of" meant "before".)  I tend to prefer the raw numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can omit all kinds of things.

> 3:00 is *three*
>
> 3:15 is *three fifteen*
>
> 2:45 is *quarter of* if the context is "Is it 3?" "No, it's quarter of."
>
> 3:30 is *half past three* or *half past* in context, but never *half to/of four*
>
> 3:05 is *five after three* or *five after* in context
>
> 2:55 is *five of three* or *five of* in context, or *two fifty five*
>
> 3:01 is *three oh one*

And, as a general but often violated convention:

1. *am* and *pm* aren't used in any context when there's a "normal" assumption
   Examples: "My flight leave at 3" (normal), or "My flight leaves at 3am" (exception, or emphasis)
2. *am* is often *in the morning* and *pm* is often *in the afternoon* or *evening*.
   Examples: "My flight is at 3 in the afternoon", or "My flight is at three in the morning".
3. 3:00 EST/EDT is *three eastern*, and the distinction between standard and daylight time is so bungled that people often trip over it.
4. As noted above, *of* can be replaced with *till* and *to* throughout.

Comment: As several people noted in comments to the question, 'of' can be replaced by till or to. "It's a quarter to four."

Comment: @mkennedy Good point... I added that when I fixed the formatting.